# AFNetworking POST file fails (echonest?)

Tags: ios, post, afnetworking

I am trying to post a sound to echo nest for file analysis. The POST method is no different than any other method, and I believe it's not echonest dependent.

Here is the documentation. I need the "upload" part.

http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/track.html

```
NSURLRequest *request = [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"track/upload", self.apiKey] parameters:dictionary constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"track" fileName:[path lastPathComponent] mimeType:@"multipart/form-data"];
}];
AFURLConnectionOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"done");
    NSLog(@"response: %@", operation.responseString);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error.description);
    NSLog(@"response: %@", operation.responseString);
    NSLog(@"headers: %@", operation.request.allHTTPHeaderFields.description);
    NSLog(@"operation url: %@", operation.request.URL.absoluteString);
}];
```

However, I have problems. Here is my response:

```
 {"response": {"status": {"version": "4.2", "code": 4, "message": "track - Missing Parameter: track or url is required with a POST content-type of \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" or \"multipart/form-data\""}}}
```

I thought I have already given the "track" parameter to be the data I initialized. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use CharlesProxy to see what you're actually sending on the wire.

Comment: Hasn't solved my problem, but +1 because you showed me a very helpful program.

Comment: Well, that's a start I guess :-) Does the charlesproxy output show you are sending a 'track' section? If not, do their 'curl' examples work for you? If they do, compare what charlesproxy shows for the curl and for your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced same problem few weeks ago. And here is what i found.
AFNetworking makes slightly wrong multipart/form-data request.

In AFHTTPClient.m file,

```
static inline NSString * AFMultipartFormFinalBoundary() {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@--%@--%@%@", kAFMultipartFormCRLF, kAFMultipartFormBoundary, kAFMultipartFormCRLF, kAFMultipartFormCRLF];
}
```

They put kAFMultipartFormCRLF twice at the end of final boundary of a request.
But Echonest only except request with one CRLF at the end of multipart/form-data post request.
I don't know which one is exactly the righteous way in terms of HTTP protocol standard, but if you modify that code line (remove a kAFMultipartFormCRLF), i think your code would work well.

FYI, while writing this answer, I explored current AFNetworking Git repo, and found out that this defect has been fixed just 5 days ago. So i guess you can just use latest source code to fix the problem.